# Is there a periodic color scale?

Tags: plotting, color

When I want to plot the phase of the wave as follows:

```
DensityPlot[Arg[Exp[I x]], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

I get a plot with a sharp boundary when the phase reaches pi or minus pi. Is there a way of selecting a color scale which circulates smoothly?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can use `Hue[]`, or `ColorData["BalancedHue"]`, or `ColorData["MidShiftBalancedHue"]`.

Comment: Extend @ J. M.'s ennui hint to `DensityPlot[...,ColorFunction -> ColorData["BalancedHue"] , Exclusions -> None]`